# Missing zlib: cannot build Cairo for use in C++ project on Windows

Tags: c++, libraries, zlib, cairo

I'm attempting to use Cairo as part of a C++ project. I'm new to dealing with 3rd party libraries so I'm unsure of what I'm doing and if I've missed any steps. I'm also interested in learning how to correctly download, build and include 3rd party libraries in the most consistent way possible.

Steps so far:

- Installed MinGW64 & MSYS2.
- Added both bin folders to system PATH (c:\mingw64\bin & c:\msys\mingw64\bin).
- Downloaded source code from [here](https://www.cairographics.org/releases/).
- When running ./configure resolved missing pkg-config and libpng packages by downloading via pacman with no issue.
- Run `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib` in the shell.

I'm now being told that I'm missing zlib and receiving this error

```
checking whether cairo's script surface backend feature could be enabled... no (requires zlib http://www.gzip.org/zlib/)
configure: error: recommended script surface backend feature could not be enabled
```

When checking the bin folder of MSYS2, the zlib.dll file is present, and using the shell tells me that I already have it installed as it is a dependency of libpng.

The aim is to build Cario and it's dependencies into a format that I can use in my project on Windows 10.

Comment: The most consistent way is to use a package and dependency manager like Conan or vcpkg. I recommend to use VC++ on Windows. If you want to use GCC you can use WSL. MinGW can be hacky in some situations.

Comment: Are MinGW/MSYS2 not the "proper" way to do this then? I looked at Conan and vcpkg for Cairo but the Google results seemed like everyone was still struggling. I'm confused as to why it's so hard to just build the library when it seems to be so widely used.

Comment: _"I'm confused as to why it's so hard to just build the library when it seems to be so widely used."_ I'd say the main problem is Windows because most of these open source C++ developers work with Linux but it could also be my subjective perception. `cairo` is already available at https://conan.io/center/cairo as pre built Windows library but only for VSC++.

Comment: With MinGW on Windows you are going the hardest way. Usually you'll find documentation and support for Windows and VSC++, Linux and GCC and Mac and Clang.

Comment: Cairo's latest development snapshot supports building with meson. If I understand things correctly, meson can automatically build and download dependencies where needed, but I do not really know the details.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need either `mingw-w64-i686-zlib` or `mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib`.

The `zlib1.dll` you found in MSYS2's `/usr/bin` (`/bin`?) is the MSYS runtime's version, and built against the POSIX-y environment MSYS2 lends from Cygwin.

The libraries you will use and build upon when compiling with the MinGW-w64  compilers available through MSYS2's package repositories are put in `/mingw32` and `/mingw64` subdirectories for 32 and 64-bit versions, respectively.

Comment: I should have specified that the bin folder I was talking about was msys/mingw64/bin and that the zlib.dll file was present in there. I have used "pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib" to install zlib. Have updated post.

Comment: Just as a check: you know there is an MSYS2 cairo package right? From your question I gathered you didn't want to use it for some reason. What you need to do is figure out what exactly cairo's configure script is trying to detect zlib, and perhaps that needs fixing. You are running a MinGW64 command prompt, right?

Comment: Yes I'm aware, I am just too ignorant to know what to do with that package once it's installed. I tried researching as I'm unfamiliar with MSYS etc but I didn't understand enough of it to know what the next steps would be.

Comment: You generally use something like CMake or autotools or pkgconfig to "find" that package (and using the MSYS2 packages that should work flawlessly). Deployment is left up to you, so you'll need to figure out which DLLs you need to ship with your application (if you're going to deploy an application).

Comment: That's the bit where I'm tripping up, as far as I'm aware I haven't done anything wrong, but pkg-config is not finding the zlib1.dll despite it being present in the folder.

Comment: @CodeMonkey210399 It looks like you really want to do it the hardest way possible. I would discourage the use of mingw since the linker totally sucks - for plenty enough C++ code it takes an order of magnitude more time to link than msvc’s linker, and it runs out of resources (I’m not joking). Start with msvc as a provider of compiler+SDK, and use cmake to find various packages and use them in your project. There’s lots of cmake docs and posts about pointing `FindXyzpackage` (specific to each package) into the right location so it finds what it needs. Posix-ness is not practical on Windows.

Comment: So I'd be better off learning how to use CMake then byt the sounds of it?